# Sort answers by content length for TLDR people

Tags: feature-request, answers

Sometimes the topvoted answer is too long and complicated and many people want a 1-line solution to their problem. Currently there are 3 ways to sort the answers. It will be great if we can sort the answers by content length showing the shortest answers on top.
What do you guys think about adding such a feature?

**Edit:** Seeing the downvotes and the total disagreement this was probably a bad idea(sounded cool in my mind)

Comment: We don't want *short* answers unless they are the *best* answers.

Comment: An answer being a short, 1-line solution does not necessarily mean it's a _good_ and _working_ solution that will actually help you. Honestly, and _**this is pure opinion**_ from here on, I think the best way to _learn_ from an answer is to _understand_ the answer, and why that answer solves the problem. For that reason, I don't appreciate short, 1-line solutions unless they're extremely simple and only need a sentence or two of explanation.

Comment: @Paulie_D it will be another sort option just like `active` `oldest` and `votes` and not the default. maybe named `short`

Comment: *What* it would be isn't relevant here.

Comment: Well `oldest` and `active` don't give you the best answers either. It's just a sorting option. Giving more options to people isn't bad

Comment: TLDR people aka. the copy&paste generation.

Comment: Oldest and active both have their uses. Example: You are at a company using old products, and cannot upgrade. You have an issue with your IDE, but it's an older version and finding an answer is hard. You find an old question on SO about your issue, asked around the time your IDE version was widely used. You see newer answers about newer versions, so you sort "oldest" to find answers more likely to be relevant to your version. Similarly with active, if you're using the _newer_ version, you can use "active" to check for updated or newer answers, more likely to be addressing your version.

Comment: I could see using this the opposite way. You could make the longer answers first because you want to see the ones that have more detail. But even that has the same problem: long doesn't necessarily mean good either. The longest answers could just have rambling or way more code than necessary.

Comment: Cause, you know, some people don't actually want to learn anything, they just want to be able to copy-pasta some code from the internet without knowing what it does or what the limitations of said code are, mash it all together, and get paid for it... right?

Comment: I always want one-line answers. If it lays golden eggs and results in world peace, so much the better.   Seriously though, this is a ... .[be nice].. less-than-useful idea:(

Comment: @TinyGiant - you missed the important ' then run!' step from the end.

Comment: Ah, the most important part. @MartinJames

Comment: This is how you get more link-only answers.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Short link, link only answers. :)

Comment: Questions that can be answered with a one-liner, are usually the questions that should get closed and deleted, unless there is a long, detailed answer raising the worth of the question…

Comment: Don't let the mob tell you it's a bad idea.  You should be able to sort _however_ you want.  The down-voters don't need to use the sort option if they don't want to.

Answer (score 7):

I have a user script that [sorts answers by the length of the first code block](https://stackapps.com/questions/4570/code-golf-se-answer-sorter). It should be easy to make it sort by total answer length instead, if you want.

Actually, just replacing the selector `pre:first` on line 33 with `.post-text` should be enough.  Of course, you may also wish to rename the script and maybe tweak the tooltip text, and change the `@match` line to make it run on SO instead of CodeGolf.SE.

Heck, let me just post the tweaked code here:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Sort SO answers by length
// @namespace  http://vyznev.net/
// @version    0.1
// @description  Add a tab to sort answers by length on Stack Overflow
// @match      *://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @copyright  2016, Ilmari Karonen
// @grant      none
// ==/UserScript==

// based on Code Golf SE sorter v0.6 from https://gist.github.com/vyznev/9b55e1f96ee129d53466

var inject = function () {
    var $votestab = $('#tabs a[href*="?answertab=votes"]:first');
    if ( !$votestab.length ) return;

    var $golftab = $votestab.clone().attr( {
        href: function (i,v) { return v.replace( /[?&]answertab=votes\b/, '?answertab=shortest' ) },
        title: "Shortest answers first"
    } ).text('shortest').removeClass('youarehere').insertAfter($votestab);

    var tab = /[?&]answertab=([^&]*)/.exec( location.search );
    tab = (tab && tab[1]) || localStorage.getItem( 'codegolf_sort_tab' ) || 'default';
    localStorage.setItem( 'codegolf_sort_tab', tab );
    if ( tab != 'shortest' ) return;

    $('#tabs a.youarehere').removeClass('youarehere').addClass('youwerehere');
    $golftab.addClass('youarehere');
    $('<style type="text/css">#tabs a.youwerehere { border-bottom: 1px dotted #ea0 }</style>').appendTo('head');

    $('.answer').each( function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var answerid = $this.data('answerid');
        if ( answerid ) $this.prepend( $this.prev('a[name="' + answerid + '"]') );
        var $code = $this.find('.post-text');
        var score = ($code.length ? $code.text().length : 1e9);
        $this.data( 'golfscore', score + Math.random() );
    } ).not('.deleted-answer, .downvoted-answer').sort( function (a,b) {
        return $(a).data('golfscore') - $(b).data('golfscore');
    } ).insertAfter('#answers-header');

    // scroll back to target post after re-sorting
    var m = /^#(?:(\d+)|comment(\d+)_\d+)$/.exec( location.hash );
    var id = m && ( m[1] ? "answer-" + m[1] : "comment-" + m[2] );
    if ( id ) document.getElementById( id ).scrollIntoView();
};

var scriptElem = document.createElement( 'script' );
scriptElem.textContent = "$(" + inject + ");";
document.body.appendChild( scriptElem );
```

Comment: Too much jQuery, otherwise it's cool

Comment: +1. If you could rewrite this to one line, this should be the accepted answer.